# VPN connection from Android emulator fails

Tags: android, android-emulator, vpn

I am new to Android development. I am trying to join an existing VPN from my Android app. I want to integrate the VPN in my app; my app then is supposed to query a remote database.

I got some code and tried to use it to create a VPN. It emulates the built-in VPN manager on the Android phone. The code compiles and the manager is launched but the connection to the VPN does not succeed when I try to connect after all configuration. The protocol is PPTP. A VPN exists and has been tested.

I tried connecting from an android phone with the same settings and it was successful.

I thought maybe I am passing the parameters in the wrong way. I have put the code for the vpn part below. The url is not the actual but in same format.

Any help to identify what I am doing wrong would be appreciated. Also if there is a way I can directly call the VPN manager from my app.

Thanks very much for any help,

---

```
final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
final Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS"));
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                String registrationUrl = String.format("daffy.zune.org");
                url = new URL(registrationUrl);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "Registration success");
                } else {
                    Log.w("MyApp", "Registration failed for: " + registrationUrl);              
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.register);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to manually connect to the VPN, switch back to your app, and then connect to the remote database?

Comment: I think you need to make sure whether you need to establish a HTTPS or HTTP connection my guess would be you need to make an HTTPS connection in order to register.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at the [simplevpn](http://code.google.com/p/simplevpn/) project and browse the [source here](http://code.google.com/p/simplevpn/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/baueran/AndroidSimpleVPN%253Fstate%253Dclosed) and view [ShowAllVPNsActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/simplevpn/source/browse/trunk/src/baueran/AndroidSimpleVPN/ShowAllVPNsActivity.java).

Hope this helps! We need more good VPN apps in the Market!